# Как брать данные с ThingHTTP с помощью nodemcu v3(esp8266)?

Tags: api, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

с помощью сайта ThingSpeak в разделе ThingHTTP я получаю данные с одного сайта, при проверке api все замечательно, данные приходят без ошибок и теперь мне надо с этого api получать те самые данные и хранить их в переменной в nodemcu v3(esp8266).

```
 
const char* ssid     = "KBTU_wireless";
const char* password = "KBTUwireless!";
 
const char* host = "api.thingspeak.com";
 

 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
 
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
 
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
 
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected"); 
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
}//end setup
 
void loop() {

WiFiClient Client;

const int httpsPort = 80;

if (!Client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {

Serial.println("connection failed");

}

String url = "https://api.thingspeak.com/apps/thinghttp/send_request?api_key=967QSN6K892SR33T";

Client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +

"Host: " + host = "\r\n" );

String line = Client.readStringUntil('\r');

Serial.println(line);



}
```

вроде код правильный но у меня получаются только пробелы и больше ничего

вот api https://api.thingspeak.com/apps/thinghttp/send_request?api_key=967QSN6K892SR33T

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: есть сайт iqair.com где показывается индекс качества воздуха в реальном времени и мне нужно получать значение с этого сайта, esp8266 не сможет сама спарсить необходимые данные поэтому воспользовался сайтом thingspeak.com которая сама достает эти данные и создает api по которому esp может с легкостью достать их, я написал примерный код но он не работает, в консоль вместо значении выводится ПРОБЕЛЫ то есть ничего.

Comment: @АлибекНахимов Ну, вы используете https в запросе, а это как минимум нужно использовать WiFiClientSecure, там есть свои особенности, посмотрите примеры. Либо использовать http протокол, если сервис позволяет. Попробовал зайти через http по вашей ссылке - показывает 83 чего то.